# Get current date everyday for a Windows service

Tags: c#

I want to run my windows service every day on only a certain time so I did the following but how do I replace this date in every day?

```
Dim checkTime As DateTime
checkTime = checkTime.Parse("7/23/2010 3:41 PM")
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a scheduled task not a service?

Comment: Just an observation, it would be nice if you accept answers if they answer your questoin. 8 questions with 0 accepts is quite low.

Comment: Is this C# or VB.NET? You've tagged the question C# but the code is VB.NET!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want it to have today's date and check for exactly 3:41PM you can do:

```
DateTime checkTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(15).AddMinutes(41);
```

You have the C# tag but your code is in VB so the VB equivalent is:

```
Dim checkTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.[Date].AddHours(15).AddMinutes(41)
```

Comment: Personally I prefer DateTime.Today as apposed to DateTime.Now.Date

Answer (score 1):

Does your program need to be running at all times, or does it simply need to execute a function at a specific time and when done, quit?

If the latter, you could simply use Windows' [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(VS.85).aspx) to schedule your EXE to run on a regular basis.

If the former, there's still no need to reinvent the wheel.  Take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).  It is an extremely robust job scheduling library that allows you to schedule jobs to run on a regular basis.  Basically, you create a class inheriting from `IJob` and its `Execute()` method will be called by Quartz at the appointed time(s).

Word of warning: Quartz is multi-threaded and your `IJob` class' `Execute()` will be called on a thread separate from your main thread, so you're thus exposed to the dangers of threading.